# cannot read /proc files during android boot up

Tags: android

I am writing a bootup script that looks into /proc/bus/input/devices to verify touch device. The script seems to work fine by manually running it after android boot up. But cat /proc/bus/input/devices returns no output when the script is placed in init.rc file.

I thought there should be no issue reading /proc files in init.rc. Can some one help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the proc filesystem is not yet mounted at the point in time when you are trying to do this?  Or what you are trying to read could be implemented by a module which is not yet loaded (though that seems less likely on android).  Or you could have some bug in your code - can you try with something really basic like /proc/version ?

Comment: I checked the proc mount with ls /proc command in the script and I get the list of directories(bus/devices/input) under /proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The problem was I was starting my service too soon, since it was under class main. starting the script manually during zygote startup solved the problem for me.